# What's wrong with this batch code?

Tags: batch

Can someone help how to find whats wrong with this code?
Basically its only a part of the script i made to fix somethings and i can get the result of "DCHP Status" gives a blank result or invalid answer like a dhcp lan display NO.
I can't use powershell in some machines so need to use batch.

basically, the code uses psexec to connect a remote computer on lan and run the script based on DHCP or static IP and fix something's so i connect properly using sccm remote.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Disabling UAC
echo Disabling UAC
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v "EnableLUA" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f >nul
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f >nul

:: Listing all network adapters
echo List all network adapters
netsh interface show interface
echo.

:: Getting the name of the network adapters
echo Enter the interface name you want to fix:
set /p adapterName=

:: Validating the user input
if not defined adapterName (
    echo You must enter a network adapter name!
    exit /b
)

:: Running ipconfig and storing the output in a temporary file
echo Run ipconfig and store the output in a temporary file
ipconfig > ipconfig.txt
REM ipconfig /all > dhcp.txt
netsh interface ip show addresses name="%adapterName%" > dhcp.txt

:: Parsing the IP address, subnet mask, and default gateway from the output
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /i /c:"IPv4 Address" ipconfig.txt') do (
    set "ip=%%A"
    set "ip=!ip: =!"
)

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%B in ('findstr /i /c:"Subnet Mask" ipconfig.txt') do (
    set "mask=%%B"
    set "mask=!mask: =!"
)

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%C in ('findstr /i /c:"Default Gateway" ipconfig.txt') do (
    set "gateway=%%C"
    set "gateway=!gateway: =!"
)

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%D in ('findstr /i /b /c:"DHCP Enabled" dhcp.txt') do (
    set "DHCP=%%D"
    set "DHCP=!DHCP: =!"
    if /i "!DHCP!"=="Yes" (
        set "DHCPStatus=Yes"
    ) else (
        set "DHCPStatus=No"
    )
)

if /i "%DHCPStatus%"=="Yes" (
    goto :dhcp
) else (
    goto :static
)

:dhcp
echo.
echo Actual network configuration of host
echo IP Address: !ip!
echo Subnet Mask: !mask!
echo Default Gateway: !gateway!
echo DHCP: !DHCPStatus!
echo.

:static
echo.
echo Actual network configuration of host
echo IP Address: !ip!
echo Subnet Mask: !mask!
echo Default Gateway: !gateway!
echo DHCP: !DHCPStatus!
echo.
```

[image: error]

Entire code:

```bash
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_xptoKey=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters"
set "_ipv6Key=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters"
set "_UACKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"

echo/Disabling UAC & for %%i in =;( EnableLUA,ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin 
    );= do >nul reg add "!_UACKey!" /v "%%~i" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

:: Listing all network adapters interfaces
echo/List all network adapters & netsh interface show interface

:: Getting the name of the network adapters and validating the user input
echo/ & set /p "_adapterName=Enter the interface name you want to fix: " || =;(
     echo You must enter a network adapter name! & exit /b );=

:: Parsing the IP address, subnet mask, and default gateway from the output
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:(" %%A in =;('
     ipconfig /all ^| findstr /ic:"IPv4"
    ');= do set "_ip=%%~B" && call set "_ip=%%_ip: =%%"

for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:(" %%A in =;('
     ipconfig /all ^| findstr /ic:"Sub"
    ');= do set "_Sub=%%~B" && call set "_Sub=%%_Sub: =%%"
    
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:(" %%A in =;('
     ipconfig /all ^| findstr /ic:"Gate"
    ');= do set "_Gate=%%~B" && call set "_Gate=%%_Gate: =%%"

:: Showing the current settings obtained
echo/Actual Network Configuration of Host
echo/     IP Address: !_ip!
echo/    Subnet Mask: !_sub!
echo/Default Gateway: !_gate!
echo/           DHCP: !_dhcp! & echo/ 

:: Applying configurations and executing common commands
echo/Disabling & =;( 
     echo/Disabling network adapter... Please Wait... >con
     netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" disable 
     timeout /nobreak 6 | echo/ Enabling network adapter... Please wait... >con
     netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" enable
     timeout /nobreak 6 | echo/ >con 
    );= >nul 2>&1

:: Set the IP address, subnet mask, gateway, DNS servers if the current IP is not static
netsh interface ip show addresses name="!_adapterName!" | findstr "DHCP.*Yes" >nul || =;(
     echo/Configuring the network settings...
     netsh interface ipv4 set address name="!_adapterName!" source=static address="!_ip!" mask="!_sub!" gateway="!_gate!"
     netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="!_adapterName!" static 1.1.1.1 validate=no
     netsh interface ipv4 add dns name="!_adapterName!" 1.0.0.1 index=2 validate=no
     netsh interface ipv4 delete dnsservers name="!_adapterName!" 1.2.3.4 validate=no
    );=

echo/Adding DNS sufix: [xpto.pt + xpto2.pt] 
reg add "!_xptoKey!" /f /v SearchList /t REG_SZ /d "xpto.pt,xpto2.pt" >nul

echo/Disable TCP/IP v6 for the network adapter...
reg add "!_ipv6Key!" /v "DisabledComponents" /t REG_DWORD /d 0xffffffff /f >nul

for %%i in =;( "set global randomizeidentifier=disabled","isatap set state state=disabled",
     "6to4 set state state=disabled","set privacy state=disable","set teredo disable"
    );= do netsh interface IPV6 %%~i 

echo/Testing Network Connection (DHCP^)...
ping -n 4 10.0.25.80 | findstr "ms loss" | sort /Uniq

echo/Running Flushdns and Registerdns... & >nul =;( 
     ipconfig /flushdns & ipconfig /registerdns 
    );= 2>&1 | findstr "IP Cache" | Sort /Uniq

timeout /nobreak 5 | endlocal & goto :eof
```

Comment: What does this code do for you now? What is the overall purpose of the script? I think you're trying to tell us what happens when the code runs, but could you use punctuation and formatting and possibly more clear statements to indicate the current output of this? Have you run each line one at a time to see what happens?

Comment: Post the contents of dhcp.txt as your script reads the file and looks for a string. [Edit[ your question to include details of what the script is doing as it's currently written.

Comment: Oh my!  It's so funny.. the `whats wrong with this batch code` question .. even in title alone is crack to 80% of us here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to create temporary files and have to delete them after manipulating them to get the desired result, you can use a doble `for` loop to get your strings directly from the command output, and also observing that the `:static` label basically reproduces the same as the `:DHCP` label, so you can use `echo variables` without a `:specific` label for `:each`...

---

```bash
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_xptoKey=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters"
set "_UACKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"

echo/Disabling UAC & for %%i in =;( EnableLUA,ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin 
    );= do >nul reg add "!_UACKey!" /v "%%~i" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
    
echo/List all network adapters & netsh interface show interface & echo/

:: Getting the name of the network adapters and validating the user input
echo/ & set /p "_adapterName=Enter the interface name you want to fix: " || =;(
     echo You must enter a network adapter name! & exit /b );=

:: Parsing the IP address, subnet mask, and default gateway from the output    
for %%G in =;( IPv4,Sub,Gate );= do for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:(" %%A in =;('
     ipconfig /all ^| Find "%%~G" ');= do set "_%%~G=%%~B" && call set "_%%~G=%%_%%~G: =%%"

:: Showing the current settings obtained
echo/ & echo/Actual network configuration of host
echo/     IP Address: !_IPv4! &  echo/    Subnet Mask: !_Sub!
echo/Default Gateway: !_Gate! &  echo/           DHCP: !_DHCP! & echo/ 

:: Applying configurations and executing common commands
echo/Disabling & =;( 
     echo/Disabling network adapter... Please Wait... >con
     netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" disable 
     timeout /nobreak 6 | echo/ Enabling network adapter... Please wait... >con
     netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" enable
     timeout /nobreak 6 | echo/ >con 
    );= >nul 2>&1

:: Set the IP address, subnet mask, gateway, DNS servers if the current IP is not static
netsh interface ip show addresses name="!_adapterName!" | findstr "DHCP.*Yes" >nul || =;(
     echo/Configuring the network settings...
     netsh interface ipv4 set address name="!_adapterName!" source=static address="!_ip!" mask="!_sub!" gateway="!_gate!"
     netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="!_adapterName!" static 1.1.1.1 validate=no
     netsh interface ipv4 add dns name="!_adapterName!" 1.0.0.1 index=2 validate=no
     netsh interface ipv4 delete dnsservers name="!_adapterName!" 1.2.3.4 validate=no
    );=

>nul =;(
     echo/Adding DNS sufix: [xpto.pt + xpto2.pt] >con:
     echo/reg add "!_xptoKey!" /f /v SearchList /t REG_SZ /d "xpto.pt,xpto2.pt" 
    
     echo/Disable TCP/IP v6 for the network adapter... >con:
     echo/reg add "!_xptoKey:p\=p6\!" /v "DisabledComponents" /t REG_DWORD /d 0xffffffff /f 
    );= 2>&1

for %%i in =;( "set global randomizeidentifier=disabled","isatap set state state=disabled",
     "6to4 set state state=disabled","set privacy state=disable","set teredo disable"
    );= do netsh interface IPV6 %%~i 

echo/Testing Network Connection (DHCP^)...
ping -n 4 10.0.25.80 | findstr "ms loss" | sort /Uniq

echo/Running /Flushdns and /RegisterDNS... & >nul =;( 
     ipconfig /flushdns & ipconfig /registerdns 
    );= 2>&1 | findstr "IP Cache" | Sort /Uniq

timeout /nobreak 5 | endlocal & goto :eof
```

---

- Or closest alternative to your original code...

---

```bash
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo/Disabling UAC & for %%i in =;( EnableLUA,ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin 
    );= do >nul reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v "%%~i" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

:: Listing all network adapters
echo/List all network adapters & netsh interface show interface

:: Getting the name of the network adapters and validating the user input
echo/ & set /p "_adapterName=Enter the interface name you want to fix: " || =;(
     echo You must enter a network adapter name! & exit /b );=

:: Parsing the IP address, subnet mask, and default gateway from the output
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:(" %%A in =;('
     ipconfig /all ^| findstr /ic:"IPv4"
    ');= do set "_ip=%%~B" && call set "_ip=%%_ip: =%%"

for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:(" %%A in =;('
     ipconfig /all ^| findstr /ic:"Sub"
    ');= do set "_Sub=%%~B" && call set "_Sub=%%_Sub: =%%"
    
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:(" %%A in =;('
     ipconfig /all ^| findstr /ic:"Gate"
    ');= do set "_Gate=%%~B" && call set "_Gate=%%_Gate: =%%"

netsh interface ip show addresses name="%_adapterName%" | findstr "DHCP.*Yes" >nul && =;(
    set "_dhcp=Yes" && goto :dhcp );= || set "_dhcp=No" && goto :static

:dhcp
echo/
echo/Actual network configuration of host
echo/     IP Address: !_ip!
echo/    Subnet Mask: !_sub!
echo/Default Gateway: !_gate!
echo/           DHCP: !_dhcp! & echo/ 
endlocal & goto :eof

:static
echo/
echo/Actual network configuration of host
echo/     IP Address: !_ip!
echo/    Subnet Mask: !_sub!
echo/Default Gateway: !_gate!
echo/           DHCP: !_dhcp!
echo/           DHCP: !_dhcp! & echo/ 
endlocal & goto :eof
```

---

Note that you are currently executing a command redirecting the output and submitting this output to a file for manipulation in a loop and checking if you have yes/no in the line to define this variable and bring the execution to a flow control (`goto :DHCP` or `goto :static` label), but one line does this without the need for all that step above.

See a use of `findstr` for a condition with a multiplicity of strings to be searched for in a line/output (`findstr String1.*String2`) of your command and redirected to an operator that will directly define your variable depending on whether it results in true/success (`&&`) or false/failure (`||`):

If the string `DHCP` + one or more characters (`.*`) + `Yes` is found on the same line returns `true`, the following execution will be what comes after `&& (executes these commands)`, but if the execution returns `false`, the multiple strings are not found on the same line, the operator `|| (execute this block)`:

```
netsh interface ip show addresses name="%_adapterName%" | findstr "DHCP.*Yes" >nul && =;(
    set "_dhcp=Yes" && goto :dhcp );= || set "_dhcp=No" && goto :static
```

---

Finally, always consider adding an `Endlocal` when using `Setlocal`, especially if there will be multiple executions of the same bat without closing the current session.

---

**PS.**: Consider **[DavidPostill♦'s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1833896/969781)**, the core of his undefined variable was the use of `/B` in your `findstr`... command.

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Goto :lable /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [`Findstr /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Where does **`GOTO :EOF`** return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/8177207)
- [`Set variable=variable:substrings` | DOS - String Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: I post in topic the entire code i need with your code. Can you check and see if i need to simplify the code or change to work better? basically, the code uses psexec to connect a remote computer on lan and run the script based on DHCP or static IP and fix something's so i connect properly using sccm remote.

Comment: I'll do that, yes, but as soon as I have more time **// Done!**

Answer (score 1):

#### "DCHP Status" gives a blank result

`findstr /i /b /c:"DHCP Enabled" dhcp.txt` is broken as written.

- `/b` Match pattern if at the Beginning of a line.
- `/c:"string"` Use string as a literal search string (may include spaces).

However:

> To match an entire phrase/sentence or to use Regular Expressions use the `/C` **and** `/R` options.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So you need to either remove `/b` **or** add `/r`.

Removing `/b` works for me:

```
F:\test>type dhcp.txt

Configuration for interface "Wireless Network Connection"
    DHCP enabled:                         Yes
    IP Address:                           192.168.188.250
    Subnet Prefix:                        192.168.188.0/24 (mask 255.255.255.0)
    Default Gateway:                      192.168.188.251
    Gateway Metric:                       0
    InterfaceMetric:                      25


F:\test>findstr /i /c:"DHCP Enabled" dhcp.txt
    DHCP enabled:                         Yes

F:\test>
```

You also need to change your `for` loop as follows:

```
F:\test>type test.cmd
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=3" %%D in ('findstr /i /c:"DHCP Enabled" dhcp.txt') do (
    if /i "%%D"=="Yes" (
        set "DHCPStatus=Yes"
    ) else (
        set "DHCPStatus=No"
    )
    echo !DHCPStatus!
  )
endlocal

F:\test>test
Yes

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Findstr - Search for strings - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is how you use delims,...ie, you can see that;

```
/B         Matches pattern if at the beginning of a line.
```

but then you would have to "respect" your own output and actually go with;

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%D in ('findstr /i /b /c:"    DHCP enabled" dhcp.txt') do (
```

PS: this will work just as fine;

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%D in ('findstr /i /b /c:"    DHCP enabled" dhcp.txt') do (
    set "DHCPStatus=%%D"
)
```